# Create columns in Linq By using Looping

Tags: c#, linq, join

I using the linq to left join another data table, this make me need to using Linq to create columns for new leftjoin data table.

Is it anyway to loop through the columns to create it automatically in linq?

```
 var Dt1JoinDt2 = from dr1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                  join dr2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                  on dr1.Field<Int64>(id1) equals dr2.Field<Int64>(id2) into joinDt1AndDt2
                  from leftjoin in joinDt1AndDt2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select dtJoinedTable.LoadDataRow(new object[]
                  {
                   dr1.Field<String>("id"),
                   dr1.Field<Int64?>("col_sample"),
                   dr1.Field<String>("col2"),
                   dr1.Field<String>("colName"),
                   dr1.Field<String>("columns"),
                   dr1.Field<String>("col_no"),
                   ......
```

This is the portion of code I want to use loop to create the columns

```
                   dr1.Field<String>("id"),
                   dr1.Field<Int64?>("col_sample"),
                   dr1.Field<String>("col2"),
                   dr1.Field<String>("colName"),
                   dr1.Field<String>("columns"),
                   dr1.Field<String>("col_no"),
                   ......
```

Is it anyway to do this by Linq or C# or others coding method???

Comment: is new object[] {} in your select string array?

Comment: Yes. I nid the column in dt1 and dt2

Comment: i updated the codes with assigning new string array. can you try this new method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you still need to cast to DataColumn

```
using System.Data

var Dt1JoinDt2 = from dr1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                  join dr2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                  on dr1.Field<Int64>(id1) equals dr2.Field<Int64>(id2) into joinDt1AndDt2
                  from leftjoin in joinDt1AndDt2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select dtJoinedTable.LoadDataRow(
                   (from dc1 in dt1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() select dc1.ColumnName).ToArray() // cast to DataColumn, use joinDt1AndDt2
                  .Union((from dc2 in dt2.Columns.Cast<DataColumn> select dc2.ColumnName).ToArray())
                  )
```

Comment: How about the left join columns?
I need the original column from dt1 and also leftjoin's column? @@

Comment: But the joinDt1AndDt2 actually just hav dt2 columns not include dt1 columns

Comment: do you want both dt1 and dt2 columns?

Comment: I edited to get all columns from dt1 and dt2, is it what u expecting?

Comment: Yes. I think this is what I want. But it gv me another error like 
Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <id> in id Column.  Expected type is Int64.

I think before I change it to dynamic column I have put something like dr1.Field<Int64?>("id") to solve this similar issue.

So how can I do the same thing in this linq?

Comment: this is gonna be tricky. you have to use Convert.ToInt32() and where clause

Comment: maybe you can try with ToString() for int value. string will remain string but int will convert to string

Comment: Not so sure how to apply the solution you provide, but I think I will open another question regarding this. Thanks for your help ^^

Comment: I have try that as the changes you made before, it gv me the same error also.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <System.String[]> in id Column.  Expected type is Int64.

It become this error, I think it should not be cast like this.

Comment: I just realize the error is not from column name. the row with column name ""col_sample" that have integer variable. need to check how you convert from int to string in LoadDataRow

Comment: In dt1, I just create the column with Int64, cause I can't change the data type in dt2 since it alrd have data at first place, and I cannot change it. In order to make the comparing id works, I change what i can change which is create the columns in Int64 data type for dt1. Thus, I assume when it binding data, it should be in Int64.

Comment: I alrd know the issue, bcos the solution you gv me is not binding the data into the columns respectfully, it actually binding column into the where the data should be....

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a computer in hand but you can try something like:

```
dt1.Columns.AsEnumerable().Select(column => dr1[column.Name]).ToArray()
```

Comment: dt1.Columns did not have .Select option

Comment: dt1. Columns. AsEnumerable().